# Xcode and fstream error

Tags: c++, xcode7, fstream

I was writing a program in c++ last week that was utilizing file operations, and I wrote the program with everything correct.

I did all the necessary steps to do with using file io, but for some reason my

```
If (!inFile) { cout << "input file could not be opened."  << endl; }
```

Would appear on every run. The input file was in the same directory as my cpp file. I figured this could have been some glitch with Xcode (seeing as every version has some kind of issue.) and I decided to make a new project just to make sure it wasn't an error there. Still nothing. So I decided to use the terminal. I tested my program with g++ on the terminal. Running it on the terminal ran with no issues at all.

I searched for days, and just couldn't find any kind of specific issues related to this issue.

My question:
Was this a bug in c++ using Xcode? Could someone explain why nothing would fix it?

Comment: You need to set the *working directory* of your project.

Comment: You should show the code where you open the file. Note also, that you need to specify the _full_ path when opening a file from within a console app.

Comment: Try explicitly calling `if (!inFile.is_open())` in case there's a weird issue with the operator overload.

Comment: The reason I asked is because visual studio/eclipse/etc will load the file fine with just the file name itself, instead of a full path, but I will try the is_open() method.